# Is $f(x;a)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cfrac{n!(1-x)^n}{(1-a)(2-a)\cdots(n-a)}$ some kind of special function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, special-functions

In deriving the solution to a differential equation I arrived at the following series expression:

$f(x;a)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cfrac{n!(1-x)^n}{(1-a)(2-a)\cdots(n-a)};\quad 0\le x \le 1$

where $a$ is a very small parameter of the equation, and is NOT an integer (otherwise the formula is not valid). After some brief analysis I found this series to be convergent, but I couldn't find a closed form expression.

Does it belong to any existing families of special functions?

Comment: the series sums to a [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) ${}_2F_1(1,1;1-a;1-x)$

Comment: Hypergeometric functions pop up a lot in solving differential equations, namely when using Frobenius series. Specifically, if $$f(x)=x^r\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$$ and $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$ forms a rational function in $k$, you have yourself a generalized hypergeometric function.

Comment: Thanks! My original differential equation arises from the forward-time Fokker-Planck equation regarding a derivative: $\frac{1}{2}\partial_x^2[x(1-x)\partial_xf]+m\partial_x^2f=\delta(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it is - it's a kind of hypergeometric function. More specifically, we rewrite it through a series of steps as

$$\begin{align}
f(x; a) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(1 - a)(2 - a) \cdots (n - a)} \frac{n!}{n!} (1 - x)^n\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n! n!}{(1 - a)(2 - a) \cdots (n - a)} \frac{(1 - x)^n}{n!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n! n!}{(1 - a)([1 - a] + 1) \cdots ([1 - a] + n - 1)} \frac{(1 - x)^n}{n!}\end{align}$$

and now converting to rising factorials, using $n! = 1^{(n)}$, we get

$$f(x; a) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1^{(n)}\ 1^{(n)}}{[1 - a]^{(n)}} \frac{(1 - x)^n}{n!}$$

which we can read off now as

$$f(x; a) =\ _2 F_1\left(\begin{matrix}1, 1 \\ 1 - a\end{matrix} \Big| 1 - x\right)$$